# How do i host angular application in godaddy vps hosting?

Tags: angular, vps

i have hosted php application in godaddy,i dont know how to host angular2 application.And i have installed node server into my hosting server.What is the next process i have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should build project Angular 2 in production mode.
[image]

After build, it will create `dist` folder. It's normal HTML, JS and other stuff relate.

Just copy into your PHP server folder and note config in index.html `<base href='/'>`

Comment: I have a doubt with "note config in index.htm <base href='/'>" please explain in detail

Comment: You can refer `base href` part in this docs https://angular.io/guide/router . In case you config <your-server>/abc , your html tag should be `<base href='/abc'>`.